# MVC Routing - Same route but show different URL

Tags: url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to re-write URL's in format A to format B.

*Format A*

www.domain.com/Users/GenericAction?action=AddUser

*Format B*

www.domain.com/Users/AddUser

I still need to route into the GenericAction action of my users controller.

```
public ActionResult GenericAction(string action)
{

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The routing is done in the global.asax file. By default I think it is domain.com/controller/action/id

Here is a good explanation on how to map routes: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299531/Custom-routes-for-MVC-Application

Comment: Yes, I am aware of how routing works and where it happens. I am looking for an exact answer to my question. The main difference is that the url is re-written while the controller action remains the same.